# .htaccess redirect link with %25 in it

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect the following link:
`http://example.com/aktionstag-r%25C3%25BCckblick` (this is a 404) to `https://example.com`
I am trying to achieve it that way but it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/aktionstag-r%25C3%25BCckblick https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^aktionstag-r\x25C3\x25BCckblick /? [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

`\x25` is to match `%25` in URL.